# Pass function callback to module component

Tags: javascript, ios, facebook, reactjs, react-native

I want to pass a callback function as parameter of a module componen like this : http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.29/docs/native-modules-ios.html#callbacks

In my index.ios.js, i have my module component call in the render function :

```
<AGTView style={styles.ARView} downloadProgress={(error, response) =>this.bridgeManager.downloadProgress}>                      
 </AGTView>
```

downloadProgress is a propTypes defined as a React.PropTypes.func

and in the bridgeManager class i have this method :

```
downloadProgress (error, response) {

        console.log("HERE");
    }
```

But React Native don't understand the method, i have the message ***No +[RCTConvert RCTResponseSenderBlock:] function*** found.
when i launch the application.

How i could pass a callback method ?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably do the following:

```
(error, response) => this.bridgeManager.downloadProgress(error, response)
```

Comment: Not exactly @Lionel. In your question you omit the (error, response) on your downloadProgress call.